# Too Much Recursion Firefox

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

I am getting the "too much recursion" error in firefox and have tracked it down to Parsley.js and this piece of code I use to populate the errors. I am also using bootstrap 3.

```
$('#EventForm').parsley({
    successClass: "",
    errorClass: "has-error",
    classHandler: function(el) {
        return el.$element.closest(".form-group");
    },
    errorsWrapper: "<span class=\"help-inline hideHelp\"></span>",
    errorTemplate: "<span></span>"
});
```

Anyone know as to why this would be happening? It's not a massive form, but it's not small either. If that even has anything to do with it.

Comment: How did you track the error down to this code?

Comment: Make sure you don't name an event handling function the same as the event attribute in the XUL element. E.g. < ... oncommand="oncommand();">  Recursion is also when a function calls itselfs.

Comment: I tracked it down by process of elimination. Kept commenting certain code that I know is running on doc ready. went away when I commented this out. came back when I put it back.

Comment: Without an actual example, it's very difficult to point to a problem. Do you have a fiddle?

Comment: Ya, I know, was just hoping someone may have had a similar problem. I'll see if I can whip something up to post.

Comment: @KrunchMuffin Having a similar problem with firefox 51 and jquery, it seems to be preceeded b y Unreachable code after return statement.